# How to keep browser open/reuse with Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

I've looked extensively through Google and Stackoverflow, but i cant find a good way to implement keeping the browser open after a run and reuse it for the next run. I have it login, get text, but it closes after. I want to keep it open so I dont have relaunch the browser, login again and take more time than necessary. Simply want to use that same webpage, refresh/update the page, and get the new text(its dhtml). I have it to run every 10 seconds or so. Here what i have so far.

```
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(""))
            {

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"");

            // Get User Name field, Password field and Login Button
            var userNameField = driver.FindElementByName("j_username");
            var userPasswordField = driver.FindElementByName("j_password");
            var loginButton = driver.FindElementByName("Submit");

            // Type user name and password
            userNameField.SendKeys("");
            userPasswordField.SendKeys("");

            // and click the login button
            loginButton.Click();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
            {
            return d.FindElement(By.ClassName(""));
            });


            // Extract resulting message and save it into result.txt
           string result = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("")).Text;
}
```

Comment: Hi, take a look at http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7010/as-to-improve-the-selenium-2-test-speed/7015#7015

Comment: What testing framework are you using?